# Product Stock Quantity - No of Products in Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible in WooCommerce to calculate the amount of products in stock minus the no of products in the cart? So

```
products in stock - products_in_cart
```

We need this so we can show 2-4 delivery days if they order more than is in stock. Normally you can use `get_stock_quantity()` to get the stock quantity, but as long as the purchase is not made that does not show stock once the purchase has been made. My current `code/shortcode` is this:

```
/**
 * Register in or out of stock text shortcode
 *
 * @return null
 */
function imwz_register_in_or_out_stock_text_shortcode() {
  add_shortcode( 'inoroutofstocktext', 'imwz_in_or_out_stock_text_check' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'imwz_register_in_or_out_stock_text_shortcode' );


function imwz_in_or_out_stock_text_check () {
  global $product;

  ob_start();

  $output = '';

  if ( ! $product->managing_stock() && ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
      echo "2-4 dagen";
  }
  elseif ($product->is_in_stock()) {
    echo "1-2 dagen";
  }

  else {
    echo "nothing to see here";
  }

  $output = ob_get_clean();

  return $output;
}
```

This only shows what is in stock and only products sold are deducted and based on that is shows text. But I need to check if in cart causes less than in stock and then show a longer delivery date.

Comment: use this link : https://github.com/jamesgol/woocommerce-cart-stock-reducer

Comment: Hmm, see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/allow-backorders/ and https://github.com/jamesgol/woocommerce-cart-stock-reducer/issues/75 . We want to work with backorders so they can order when out of stock, but then show longer delivery days. And that does not seem to be possible yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following to know how many pieces of a certain product are in the shopping cart

```php
global $product;

// Get product id
$product_id = $product->get_id();

// Cart not empty   
if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() >= 1 ) {
    // set variable
    $in_cart = false;

    // loop through the shopping cart
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Get quantity in cart
        $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

        // match
        if ( $product_in_cart === $product_id ) {
            $in_cart = true;
        }
    }

    // product found
    if ( $in_cart ) {
        echo 'product is in het winkelwagentje, met ' . $quantity . 'stuks';
    }
}
```

Comment: This could help. Then I would only need to add code to check quantity in stock for a product and deduct quantity in stock and then display text if <= 0. Also realized I wonder how I could do this if I have some in cart that are in stock and others that are not. perhaps I need to do this code on the product page instead based on items in cart. That should be possible at least. Will have to rethink it some. Thanks for your input thus far.